# Flutter Riverpod: pub get failed

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, riverpod

I'm currently trying to study using flutter riverpod but i get a problem when i'm trying to put flutter_riverpod package i get this error

```
Because riverpod depends on flutter_riverpod ^0.9.1 which depends on riverpod ^0.8.0, riverpod ^0.8.0 is required.
So, because riverpod is 1.0.0+1, version solving failed.
Running "flutter pub get" in riverpod...
pub get failed (1; So, because riverpod is 1.0.0+1, version solving failed.)
```

What can i do to fix this problem? I tried to add riverpod package but it's also not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this decision tree](https://riverpod.dev/docs/getting_started#what-package-to-install) created by the developer of riverpod for which version to install.

You only want to install **one** riverpod dependency.

In short, if you are using [flutter_hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks) (which I would personally recommend), install [hooks_riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/hooks_riverpod). If you are not using hooks, install [flutter_riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_riverpod).

If you are writing pure dart code (no Flutter), then install [riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod).

To reiterate, your pubspec.yaml should only ever include one riverpod dependency.

If you still have version solving issues with your dependencies after this then try deleting your pubspec.lock and reinstall your dependencies.

Comment: I already put the latest version of flutter_riverpod package only to my pubspec depedencies but it falied to get the package. Maybe i need to try the last method you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, it worked although instead of deleting only the pubspec.lock, i delete the whole file because i don't add anything to it yet

Answer (score 9):

I think you should open your `pubspec.yaml`

at first line. probably your name is riverpod

My issue as well like you. name was `flutter_riverpod`

Answer (score 3):

Check if your project name is `riverpod`
For me, that was the issue...
Just use a different name for your project.

Answer (score 0):

[open you pubspec.yaml file [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygVQq.png)

open you pubspec.yaml file check  if the name is riverpod (name: riverpod)  if so just create another flutter project and  add the dependency again.

That's it